# Space between images in wordpress portfolio gallery

Tags: css, wordpress, image-gallery

I'm trying to fine-tune my [website](http://www.20watt.nl), but I can't figure out how to increase the space between images inside any of my portfolio galleries ([example](http://www.20watt.nl/portfolio/bruiloft-den-haag/)).

I've gone through the style.css file, but I must be missing something. Vertical spacing looks okay, but there's no horizontal spacing and images appear to be glued together.

I'm using wordpress with "Folio White" Theme.

Answer (score 2):

Just add this class to any css file: and add that css in header or footer for best result

```
.gallery-item {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can create new class into your theme's style.css

```
#portfolio-wrap .col{margin-top: 1%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easy if you use your right click and inspect element, you just need to add this to your style.css:

```
.gallery-item {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Be sure that your styles load before the styles used in the plugin.

Comment: Tom, Thanks! This worked perfectly - I recall trying sometimes like this earlier, but just have done something wrong- super-easy indeed.

Comment: @20Watt: my pleasure, don't forget to check this as the answer to the question

Answer (score 0):

for vertical margins you may add a class to match your desired margin by one of the following:

```
.only-top {margin-top:5px}
.only-bottom {margin-bottom:5px}
.top-and-bottom {margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:5px}
.overall {margin:5px}
.top-and-bottom-autosides {margin:5px auto}
.specific {margin:5px 4px 5px 4px} //note the order is: top right bottom left
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootsrtap method, like in rows and containers. This method better, cause it stretches the gallery width of the container.

```
.gallery {
  margin: -15px;
}

.gallery-item {
  padding: 15px;
}
```